# How to test node data chunking function

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, tdd, node.js-tape

I'm working on a project which uses node and we're trying to achieve 100% coverage of our functions. This is the only function we haven't tested, and it's within another function.

```
 var userInput = "";
    req.on("data", function(data){
      userInput += data;
    });
```

How do you go about testing this function? We tried exporting the function from another file but no luck.

I should mention that we are using tape as a testing module.

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger this "data" event on req. So that this callback will be called.

For instance, let's suppose you have `req` on your test, you could do something like that (this is Mocha):

```
req.trigger('data', 'sampleData');
expect(userInput).to.equal('sampleData');
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm using tape to test. Do you think it will work in a similar way regardless?

Comment: Yes I think it would. Can you please test the following: ```req.emit('data', 'sampleData'); console.log(userInput);``` and see if it prints 'sampleData' - otherwise try the suggestion from @eljefedelrodeodeljefe

Answer (score 1):

`req.emit('data', {sampleData: 'wrongOrRightSampleDataHere'})` should do it. 
When instantiating the `http` or hence the `req` object make sure you instantiate a new one, that no other test receives this event.

To be more complete...

```
var assert = require('assert')
function test() {
    var hasBeenCalledAtLeastOnce = false
    var userInput = "";
    // req must be defined somewhere though
    req.on("data", function(data){
        userInput += data;

       if(hasBeenCalledAtLeastOnce) {
          assert.equal(userInput, "HelloWorld", "userInput is in fact 'HelloWorld'")
       }
       hasBeenCalledAtLeastOnce = true 
    });

    req.emit('data', "Hello")
    req.emit('data', "World")

}

test()
```